# How to show that $\langle a,b \mid aba^{-1}ba = bab^{-1}ab\rangle$ is not Abelian?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, knot-theory, knot-invariants, combinatorial-group-theory

I'd like to show that
$$
G = \langle a,b \mid aba^{-1}ba = bab^{-1}ab\rangle
$$
is non-Abelian.

I have tried finding a surjective homomorphism from $G$ to a non-Abelian group, but I haven't found one. The context is that I would like to show that the figure-$8$ knot complement is non-trivial using knot groups.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If $G$ were abelian, then the relation would be equivalent to $ab^2=a^2b$, *i.e.*, $a=b$, so then $G\cong\langle a\mid \rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}$. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: It should be noted that the problem of determining whether the group defined by a presentation is abelian is, in general, undecidable.

Comment: If you're content with a computer-aided proof, you can use the free software GAP. Once it's installed, type in `F:=FreeGroup(2);; rels:=[(F.1)*(F.2)*(F.1)^(-1)*(F.2)*(F.1)*(F.2)^(-1)*(F.1)^(-1)*(F.2)*(F.1)^(-1)*(F.2)^(-1)];; G:=F/rels;; Print(AbelianInvariants(G));`. If the program terminates and outputs anything other than `[ 0 ]`, then it is not abelian. (Well, assuming my first comment is correct, anyway.)

Comment: I'd do that myself now but it's 01:50 here.

Comment: Of course, one could use `IsAbelian(G)` instead of `AbelianInvariants(G)`.

Comment: ^^  . . . and my laptop is packed away.

Comment: @Shaun: Are there any convenient types of groups that arise in knot theory for which the word problem is decidable? I don't know much about knot theory myself, and the few results I'm familiar with it are in the opposite direction.

Comment: @anomaly: That's a great question! I don't know. I'm not exactly *au fait* with knot theory either. Maybe it's worth asking that on here as a separate question. In the meantime, I'll have a look at what I can find, but I make no promises! :)

Comment: @Shaun: Cool, thanks!

Comment: @Shaun You cannot use $\mathtt{AbelianInvariants}$ to prove that a group is nonabelian. That just tells you the largest abelian quotient of the group. A better way is to use $\mathtt{LowIndexSubgroupsFpGroup}$. This group has a subgroup of index $4$ which defines a homomorphism onto $A_4$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put $\xi = \frac{1}{2}(3 + \sqrt{5})$. The map $G \to GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by
\begin{align*}
a &\to \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & \xi\end{pmatrix} & 
b &\to \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & \xi\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align*}
is well-defined with nonabelian image.

Answer (score 7):

Since you tag this with `knot-theory` and `knot-invariants`, it looks like you are trying to show the fundamental group of the knot complement $S^3-4_1$ is nonabelian.

One of the "obvious" things to try is [Fox $n$-coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_n-coloring), since they yield a homomorphism (usually surjective) to a dihedral group.  There is a $5$-coloring (using $0,4,1,2$ as you go along the knot, which you can check satisfies $2b\equiv a+c\pmod{5}$ at each crossing).  Since $5$ is a prime and the coloring is nonconstant, the corresponding homomorphism from $\pi_1(S^3-4_1)$ to $D_{2\cdot 5}$, the dihedral group of order $10$, is surjective.

Comment: Why the downvote?